# Why did Goose House do so many home recordings of their song "Sing"? Does that song have special significance to them?

Tags: history, live-music

The Goose House music group typically only does one house recording of an original or cover song (at least- after around 2012), but for one particular original song, "Sing", they've done many. I'm not too surprised about the number of recordings done in the earlier years, since I think they operated differently back then in terms of how they chose songs to play, but the number of times they did recordings of it in later years is what I find interesting.

Does "Sing" have a special significance to them? If so, is there something in particular that makes it so?

Here's a list:

- [2010 Aug. 21st](https://youtu.be/Z5PM0FhFkoQ)
- [2010 Aug. 21st](https://youtu.be/VBgzGP0ITUc) twice on the same day!
- [2010 Oct. 2nd](https://youtu.be/Qv46dvfWa8Q)
- [2010 Oct. 9th](https://youtu.be/veemHKlHB6Q)
- [2010 Oct. 16th](https://youtu.be/HJBgWizZuSk)
- [2010 Oct. 23rd](https://youtu.be/l_t88F98snM)
- [2010 Nov. 1st](https://youtu.be/iksQUFp1gDg)
- [2010 Nov. 13th](https://youtu.be/GaEQJYgQNi0)
- [2010 Nov. 27th](https://youtu.be/V58EqJxODSo)
- [2010 Dec. 11th](https://youtu.be/nUxmX76ghUs)
- [2011 Jan. 5th](https://youtu.be/GJiARx6l66A)
- [2011 Jan. 17th](https://youtu.be/_JUOD8LPHLQ)
- [2011 Jan. 31st](https://youtu.be/6e3KeO4ICKI)
- [2011 Feb. 14th](https://youtu.be/oSL2nCSD17g)
- [2011 Feb. 28th](https://youtu.be/zCtE0PgptNs)
- [2011 May 9th](https://youtu.be/EGqZM0sHBuY)
- [2011 Aug. 1st](https://youtu.be/Zjr_-7O43C4)
- [2011 Oct. 4th](https://youtu.be/PJ7xVKz8I6w)
- [2011 Nov. 30th](https://youtu.be/jfIeFt4Wou0)
- [2012 Jun. 30th](https://youtu.be/jmBDn9WyRKc)
- [2014 Feb. 27th](https://youtu.be/u4YHM2tvCPI) studio recording
- [2014 Sept. 20th](https://youtu.be/iTO-XrNnbkk)
- [2015 Nov. 20th](https://youtu.be/AwC5k3hpuGY)
- [2016 June 22nd](https://youtu.be/Fabi5cq2Vwk)
- [2016 Oct. 12th](https://youtu.be/QEEAb5WP-OM) (not on official channel)
- [2017 Oct. 27th](https://youtu.be/iFK3BTHRG_M)
- [2018 Dec. 15th](https://youtu.be/XvO8lFROzMs) (Play.Goose)

Note: special thanks to [the YouTube user](https://www.youtube.com/@goosehouse9319) (not me) who created [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5PM0FhFkoQ&list=PL5U32qOp6Uo5TaMsXPsvMeA1ysOrc5J8h&index=1) which includes most of the recordings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The song "sing" was the first original song that the group produced under the project "PlayYou.House" before it was subsequently renamed to "Goose House" and "Play.Goose".**

"PlayYou.House" was originally a project initiated by Sony Walkman for singers and songwriters to gather and stay in a share house while using the Internet to increase their influence. They used to do music live streams on Ustream starting on June 19, 2010, where on the 10th live stream (August 21, 2010), they finally managed to gather all 7 members to announce and perform their first original song, "sing". Also, **starting on October 2010, the same song was performed as an ending song for the live streams.** The project officially ended on March 26, 2011, but the group and its share house continued independently as "Goose House" until 2018 and as "Play.Goose" after that.

---

Reference:

- Japanese Wikipedia

  - [PlayYou.House](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayYou.House)
  - [Goose house](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goose_house)
  - [Play.Goose](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Play.Goose)